# Mobile web for Edit Email Settings page is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, mobile-web

I think this screenshot is enough to describe the problem:

> [image]

In case if it's not enough here is [link to your profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current). Just switch to mobile view in the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fixed now. Probably after Adam made related bug fixed: [Oops page for several tabs in mobile profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302308/339911).

Comment: Technically speaking, this was fixed right before the other bug. :) I didn't see this post, but ran into the issue while trying to reproduce the oops.

Comment: @AdamLear heh, [yesterday in ruSO chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40636559#40636559).