# Oops page for several tabs in mobile profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, 500-server-error

If you being on settings page of [you profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) select any of circled items:

> [image: settings]

And then make a switch to mobile web via link in the footer you will get "Oops page":

> [image: oops]

I think there is need to show full page if no mobile page exists for selected item like it already done for many other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some layout (in the Razor sense) weirdness at play here. The fix is live in production now. Thanks for the report!