# Huge avatar while editing profile in mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

[Edit profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) contains a huge user icon in mobile web:

> [image: huge icon]

This happens due to scaling the image horizontally to fill whole screen.

Comment: Just checked on mobile, there's no link to edit profile, only email settings. So it's a page we shouldn't be using on mobile. I guess they didn't finish working on its mobile design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes. To access edit page you need to use direct link, or switch to mobile web being on that page in full web.

Comment: So the bug is pretty minor, as we should never really get to see it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard probably the actual bug is not to add link to that page in mobile web. Page itself looks usefull. Same as other pages (look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302308/339911)).

Comment: using direct link in mobile is not intended for editing profiles. Use full site for it.

Comment: @OptimusPrime as I said above, direct link is not necessary. You can open full web page and then switch to mobile view in the footer.

Comment: @alexolut same. that is not how it supposed to work. you're playing with it.

Comment: @OptimusPrime I'm playing with whole SE network :) If such page is not designed to work in mobile then there should be a redirect to the full web version. If any page is accessed via chain of site links it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up. We’ve been doing some refactoring of our mobile web code to move layout handling to one place in preparation for the channels project.

User profile uses its own set of layouts and we missed the case where you’re viewing a desktop only view while using a mobile device / mobile theme.

Fix is in production now!

Comment: As far as I see now this page is showed as full web only. Why not to allow use it with mobile view?

Comment: It never supported mobile, the fix is just restoring the previous behaviour. As to whether it’ll ever support mobile; it’s not on any short term roadmaps and doesn’t seem to be a feature that is requested frequently

Comment: @DeanWard aka 6-8 weeks/months. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard years...?

Comment: Well, better give people some hope... ;)